# Multiple independent SPA in one page using Durandal

Tags: knockout.js, durandal

I want to host two or more single page applications in one HTML page (our legacy app). These apps should be in completely different places of pages - therefore I cannot use durandal composition for top root "shell" and do compositing using ko compose bindings. These apps should be able to communicate between themselves (router/event aggregator).

Is it possible to use Durandal and its Router plugin for such thing? What is best approach?

I tried to use multiple `applicationHost` elements and  call `app.setRoot(vm, transition, element)` with different combos of vm/element, but no luck. It seems that the last call wins...

Also I have created discussion on Durandal google groups: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/durandaljs/e6GclW0bEo0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, the only way to ensure *completely* separate apps is to use different documents - iframes or normal frames or even different windows. This is because there is a lot of shared state and, while Durandal is highly configurable, it has a number of singleton points:

- Most durandal/* components expect to work as singletons; configuration in app is shared. Subscriptions/events on app are shared. Similarly the default module lookup rules are also shared so a special "selector" (i.e. app prefix on module id) will need to be used.
- RequireJS is a singleton; require lookup rules will be shared.
- Knockout is a singleton; adding a bindingHandler will be shared in all applications.

So, while it is possible to create a bunch of "cooperative" applications (think "plugins"), each needs to be aware of the host and carefully avoid clashes. There will also need to be cooperation with module paths (i.e. prefix with the name of each app) to provide relevant lookup resolutions.

Answer (score 1):

Do you intend to have them loaded in the same HTML page? If so, then you can create different areas in the shell, one for each. Maybe a left and a right or top and bottom. Each one could be in a section or div in the shell, and use the `compose` binding to load.

You can use the eventing in Durandal to communicate between, sure.

If you load both side by side you need to decide how to respond to routing changes. If the route changes in the address bar, do you bind the active item to the left section or the right? This is up to you obviously. You may want to create a more custom approach to loading the different dashboard section content. However this really depends on how you want to reload it.

Comment: Yes, this would be possible if I can let Durandal to manage the shell for whole HTML page. But this is what I just cannot do. Structure of page where SPAs will be loaded is regular HTML page like this: 

> old html
> ...
> shell for SPA1
> ...
> old HTML
> ...
> shell for SPA2
> ...
> old HTML

Comment: sorry for formatting :) hope you can get what I think:) So I am thinking if using 2 applicationHosts is good idea and how to do it...

Answer (score 1):

You could probably host each instance of durandal in an iframe.

Comment: this is what I wanted to try also - it is not ideal solution, but might work, thx

Comment: also see discussion on Durandal google groups https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/durandaljs/e6GclW0bEo0